# How to an solve $n$th-order integral with summation in an exponent.

Tags: integration, summation, exponential-function

Salutations, I write this post because this is the first time that I see an integral of this kind, in $n$-order with a summation exponent, clarify that this just for academical curiosity about how to solve the following integral:
$$\int ... \int \exp\left(-U(X)\right) \,dx_1...\,dx_n$$
$$U(X)=\sum_{1\leq i\leq j\leq n}x_ix_j$$
Where $$X=\left(x_1,...,x_n\right); i=1,...,n $$
I would be very thankful with any guidance or explanations about how to approach this kind of exercises.

Thanks very much for your attention.

Comment: If $n=1$, the integral is $\int \exp(-x^2) \mathrm{dx}$ which has no closed form in term of usual functions.

Comment: Is this meant to be a definite integral? If so, what is the set is it integrated over?

Comment: @Chappers Salutations, this is an indefinite integral, there is no an integration interval in this case study. So, what do you suggest to solve this kind of integral then? Thanks for your interest and time.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Salutations, that's what I concluded in $n=1$, disgracefully I'm stuck in other cases, how would you analyze this case study for $x_i$ and $x_j$? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What do you mean by "indefinite integral" in the multidimensional case?

Comment: Salutations @metamorphy, apologize if I haven't been explicit, this case study has no integration intervals, that's what I meant with "indefinite integral", this happens in nth-order as it's shown in $X=\left(x_1,...,x_n\right)$ in n-dimension given by $i=1,...,n$. Hope to be clear. Thanks very much for your attention.